# DFS implementation for abstract graph in Haskell

Tags: algorithm, haskell, graph, functional-programming, depth-first-search

I am trying to implement in Haskell a DFS algorithm, which will not have access to the `Graph` internals and constructor, but only will be able to use the provided functions to retrieve all graph vertices and all node's neighbours in the graph:

```
vertices :: Eq a => Graph a -> [a]
neighbors :: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> [a]
```

As an input, the function gets a `Graph a` and an object `a`.

As an output, I am trying to provide a connected component, `Graph a`, which will have all vertices reachable from the object.

To retrieve an empty graph and add vertices I have implemented functions

```
empty :: Graph a
addVertex :: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> Graph a
```

For the `dfs`, I have so far implemented a function, which looks more like a general idea but is not even close to being working.
I feel a bit stuck, so any suggestions or tips are highly appreciated

In the end, I need to get a connected component of the graph containing the node from the input. (Not strongly connected)

So probably `dfs` itself should return a list of nodes, which then can be used to form a graph using `neighbours` function..?

So far I have this, but it still does not work correctly yet.

**The only issue I have left is to transfer keep the edges in the subgraph**

```
connectedComponent :: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> Graph a
connectedComponent g vrtx | vrtx `notElem`  vertices g = empty
                            --adds all the points to the created graph   
                          | otherwise = foldl (\graph x -> addVertex graph x) initialGraph points 
                                --gets all neighbors of the nodes retrieved in dfs
                                where 
                                    points = concatMap (neighbors g) (dfs g vrtx) 
                                    initialGraph = addVertex empty vrtx

-- Getting the Graph and a vertex to start from
dfs :: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> [a]
dfs graph node | graph == empty = []
               | [x|x<-(vertices graph),x==node] == [] = []
               | otherwise = dfs' (vertices graph) graph [node]

dfs' [] _ _ = []
dfs' _ _ [] = []
dfs' v graph (top:stack) | [x|x<-v,x==top] == [] = dfs' nextv graph stack
                     | otherwise = top : dfs' nextv graph (adjacent ++ stack)
                     where 
                        adjacent = neighbors graph top
                        --adjacent = [x | (x,y)<-e,y==top] ++ [x | (y,x)<-e,y==top]
                        nextv = [x|x<-v,x/=top]
```

Comment: I do not really see why your `dfs` aims to return a `Graph a`. Shouldn't `dfs` return a path, or a list of paths?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the way I was seeing it, is that it should return a subgraph with all the reachable nodes from the node in the input. What is called a connected component, I guess.

Comment: Or maybe it makes sense to get all the neighbors for the entire list. But then I am not sure, how to create a function connectedComponent :: Graph a -> Graph a, which will create an emtpy graph and adding all the vertices and edes inside

Comment: but then it is not DFS itself you are implementing, but an algorithm (that might make use of dfs as a subrouting): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component#Algorithms

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you, that actually makes sense, however I need to retrieve a connected component, not a strongly connected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dfs/info

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've done in the end, works correctly for me.

```
connectedComponent :: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> Graph a
connectedComponent g vrtx | vrtx `notElem`  vertices g = empty
                            --adds all the nodes and edges to the created graph   
                          | otherwise = foldl addEdge (foldl (\graph x -> addVertex graph x) initialGraph nodes) edges
                                --gets all neighbors of the nodes retrieved in dfs
                                where 
                                    nodes = concatMap (neighbors g) (dfs g vrtx) 
                                    -- init the graph with the start node
                                    initialGraph = addVertex empty vrtx
                                    edges = removeDub [(x,y) | x <- (vertices g), y <- (neighbors g x), x `elem` dfs g vrtx]

-- removes dublicates from the edges if (a,b) and (b,a) exist
removeDub ::Eq a => [(a,a)] -> [(a,a)]
removeDub [] = []
removeDub ((x,y):xs) | (y,x) `elem` xs = removeDub xs
                     | otherwise = (x,y) : removeDub xs


-- Getting the Graph and a vertex to start from
dfs :: Eq a => Graph a -> a -> [a]
dfs graph node | graph == empty = []
                 -- stop if this is the node
               | [x | x<-(vertices graph), x==node] == [] = []
               | otherwise = dfs' (vertices graph) graph [node]

-- help function for dfs
dfs' [] _ _ = []
dfs' _ _ [] = []
dfs' vs graph (top:stack) | [x | x <- vs, x==top] == [] = dfs' nextv graph stack
                        -- append the current one and go to the next node
                     | otherwise = top : dfs' nextv graph (adjacent ++ stack)
                     where
                        -- getting all neibourhs for currently viewed node 
                        adjacent = neighbors graph top
                        -- getting the next node
                        nextv = [x|x<-vs,x/=top]
```

Comment: to dfs to work you should keep track of visited nodes somewhere (in vs in your code.) It should start empty and grow as you visit nodes